# How to remove the Hover /or chage the hover color, when moving the mouse over the current username

Tags: 2013, master-page, page-layout, css

I have made some modification to my team site CSS, mainly I make the username text to be white and the background color to be blue.  This will work well till the user move the mouse over the username , then the hover colour which seems to be white will hide the username text since it is also white as follow:-

[image]
So is there a way to remove the hover over the username, or to define different hover color (something such as blue)?

The defualt view is :-
[image]

and the custom CSS is  :-

```
div#suiteBarLeft{
background-color: #008CD2 !important; 
filter: none !important;
color: #FFFFFF;
}


div#siteIcon{ 
display: none;
}



div#suiteBarRight{
background-color: #008CD2 !important; 
filter: none !important;
color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#zz4_Menu_t{

color: #FFFFFF;
}

div#zz4_Menu{

color: #FFFFFF;
}


#s4-titlerow{ 
    display: none !important;
}
#pageTitle {position: absolute; left: 400px; top: 40px;color:white;}

#uppersearch{ 
    background-color:white;background:white;color:white !important;
    }



div#welcomeMenuBox span.ms-core-menu-root { background-color: white; color: white !important; }

#SearchBox { background-color: white; }

.s4-title h1 a, .s4-title h2, .s4-title h2 a{color:white !important;}


/* Change the color of the usernames*/
#welcomeMenuBox a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF;
}
.ms-core-menu-box {
        background-color:#008CD2}

#zz5_Menu_t{
 background-color:#008CD2;   
        }
#zz5_Menu{
 background-color:#008CD2;
        }

#zz1_ID_PersonalActionMenu
{
 background-color:#008CD2; }



/* Change the color of the App page tittle*/
#pageTitle a
{
        Color:#FFFFFF;
}
</style>
.ms-welcomeMenu
{
   background-color: red;
}

for its text

.ms-welcomeMenu A:link
{
    color: red;
}

when hovering

.ms-welcomeMenu A:hover
{
    color: red;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Baring in mind that the Red color in the custom CSS will not show, i just added it for testing purposes.

Comment: Can you edit your question uploading a picture without clicking the username (default view of the page) and your css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are custom SharePoint CSS classes that you may need to overwrite to change the colour of the hovering. Using IE developer tools I found that the two classes you're looking at are `.ms-welcome-hover` and `.ms-siteactions-hover` the welcome hover class obviously being the top bar for the page.

This code in your custom CSS should change it to a blue background with black text, just adjust the colours to what you need.

```
.ms-welcome-hover, .ms-siteactions-hover
{
    background-color:#FF6666;
    color:#000000;
}
```

Regards

~Donald

Comment: i add the following :- .ms-welcome-hover, .ms-siteactions-hover
{
    background-color:red;
    color:red;
}   . but no red color will appear either for the background or for the text color ?

Comment: .ms-welcome-hover{
    background-color:#63BAE7;

    }
worked well :)

Answer (score 2):

Please concentrate on the following css classes:

**.ms-welcome-hover
.ms-siteaction-hover**

and adjust the background colors:

[image: css]

for the font color adjust this here:

[image: css2]

Comment: Chrome does a really good job on its developer tools. Just hit F12 and hover. Chrome will highlight the new CSS classes. You see clearly what's changing.

Comment: If you want to get rid of theming, there is also a good alternative: Buy one :) here http://bindtuning.com

Comment: i added the following to my cusotm CSS "  
 
i add the following :- .ms-welcome-hover, .ms-siteactions-hover { background-color:red; color:red; }" . but no red color will appear either for the background or for the text color ?

Comment: For changing the color of the name (text) when hovering use ".ms-signInLink:hover". For not hovering use ".ms-signInLink". Just like in the second screenshot ;) It should work.

Comment: unfortunelty adding these to my custom CSS ".ms-signInLink{
    background-color:#008CD2;
    color:white;
}
 .ms-signInLink:hover{
    background-color:#63BAE7;
    color:white;
} ". will still display white hover over the username which is already white !